# How to change build directory in setuptools

Tags: python, setuptools

I have a repo that I'm trying to modify to be deployable as a python package.
Unfortunately, the root of the repository has a file named `BUILD` that cannot be changed due to existing CI integrations. As a result, when I attempt to `pip install` or `python setup.py bdist_wheel` or any other permutation of using `setuptools` it fails because it cannot create a `build/` directory.

How can I change that build directory to be `_build/` or something non-conflicting?

I've tried several things like `python setup.py build -b _build` which works for the build step in isolation, but I can't find an equivalent command line argument or `setup.py` option that will let me change it for all of the subcommands of `bdist_wheel`. There seem to be a lot of moving pieces that expect to be able to create a `build` directory at some point or reference it, and I haven't been able to track them all down.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Override `build_base` in `build` command; it's used in all other distutils/setuptools commands:

```
import distutils.command.build

# Override build command
class BuildCommand(distutils.command.build.build):
    def initialize_options(self):
        distutils.command.build.build.initialize_options(self)
        self.build_base = 'my-special-build-dir'

setup(
    …
    cmdclass={"build": BuildCommand},
    …
)
```

Comment: Lifesaver. I was close, but was trying to modify `self.build_lib` instead in `run(self)`. Thank you so much kind stranger